# Remove the offset line beyond current timestamp

Tags: pine-script

I am using one of the MAs with offset of 20, but when it plots on the chart, it shows beyond the current timestamp, how can I restrict to only show upto the current timestamp?

If you see the Red line, it moves beyond current timestamp.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Cloud", shorttitle="VP", overlay=true, resolution="")
len = input(9, minval=1, title="EMA Length")
src = input(close, title="Source")
offset = input(title="Offset", type=input.integer, defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out = ema(src, len)
plot(out, title="EMA", color=color.blue, offset=offset)

//@version=4
//study(title="Moving Average", shorttitle="MA", overlay=true, resolution="")
len1 = input(9, minval=1, title="MA Length")
src1 = input(close, title="Source")
offset1 = input(title="Offset", type=input.integer, defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out1 = sma(src1, len1)
plot(out1, color=color.blue, title="MA", offset=offset1)

mashort = out
malong = out1
cloudcolour = mashort >= malong ? color.green : color.red

mashortcolor = mashort >= mashort[1] ? color.olive : color.maroon
mashortline = plot(out, title="EMA", color = color.green,linewidth = 3, offset=offset) //plot(mashort, color = mashortcolor, linewidth = 1,  title = "Short Leading EMA")
malongcolor = malong >= malong[1] ? color.green : color.red
malongline = plot(out1, color = color.red, linewidth = 3, title="MA", offset=offset1) //plot(malong, color = malongcolor, linewidth = 3,   title = "Long Leading EMA")
fill(mashortline, malongline, color = color.yellow, transp = 85, title = "MA Cloud")

highestHigh = highest(high,50)
lowestLow = lowest(low,50)
//plot(highestHigh)
//plot(lowestLow)
```

Answer (score 0):

When shifting into the future you can just reference the offset value of your variable instead of using the offset argument.

```
plot(out1[offset])
```

Comment: It doesn't work, Can you please share the whole snippet ?